# Need reference links for "[1:]" notation

Tags: python, scrapy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Primer for Python Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
sites = hxs.select('//table/tr')[1:]
```

Here i understand that scrape from second row. But i was not able to find any links to understand advanced topics on that "[1:]". Please share me any reference links

Comment: It's called "slicing". See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used to extract slices from arrays/lists.

It can be used [start:end[:ratio]]

ration is optional, and it is the jump -- ratio=2 means to extract even indexes.

if end is negative, start to count from the end of the list that number.

```
[1,2,3,4][1:-1:2]
```

means

```
[2]
```

Comment: Or odd inexes - see `[1:11:2]`.